# DropdownButton in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error :
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building GetBuilder(dirty, state: GetBuilderState#fc647):
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: .
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
dropdown.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 892 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) {
return item.value == value;
}).length == 1'

````
and here is my code 


```

    Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 0.2,
                        color: AppColor.grey,
                      ),
                      color: AppColor.lightGrey,
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        isExpanded: true,
                        hint: Text("Select Item"),
                        items: controller.countries.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
                        onChanged: (value) => controller.changeValue(value),
                        value: controller.value,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

```
controller:

 String value = ''; // Holds the selected value from the dropdown

  List<String> countries = [
    "Canada",
    "Russia",
    "USA",
    "China",
    "United Kingdom",
    "USA",
    "India"
  ];

   @override
  changeValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
    update();
  }
````

Comment: There are duplicate values in your countries list. Please make a list with unique values and try to run the code again. If your code failed to run again please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
String value = 'Select';


List<String> countries = [
"Select",
"Canada",
"Russia",
"USA",
"China",
"United Kingdom",
"USA",
"India"
];
```

The on change will work based on condition like (value!='Select' //then do something)

And try to run your app